# Azure Data Explorer-Use scalar input as column name argument in extend operator in a user-defined function

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I would like to dynamically name the calculated column, like this:

```
.create-or-alter function  ToNewName(T:(Id:string), columnName: string)
{
    T | extend columnName = Id
}
```

However, this create a new column called `columnName` instead. How do I make the second `columnName` link to the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in support for this in the language, however here is a possible workaround:

```
let foo = (p:string)
{
 print z=pack(p, 1)
 | evaluate bag_unpack(z)
}; 
foo('this is a run-time column name')
```